# Keras LSTM for continuous output and with EarlyStopping

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I wrote an LSTM regression model. It is a model with batch_size=1 and return_sequences = True for the last LSTM layer. I also set validation_data and patience for training. But there seem to be problems.

The following is my code. And I also have some basic questions.

```
# Import the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

# x and y are numpy array with shape (1,251,1)
x_test = x[:,-84:,:] # use the last 84 data as test data
y_test = y[:,-84:,:]
x_val = x[:,-36-84:-84,:] # the number of validation data is 36
y_val = y[:,-36-84:-84,:]
x = x[:,:-36-84,:] # x and y are training data
y = y[:,:-36-84,:]
# the first 36 data are not used to calculate the loss,
# set a numpy array for sample_weight used in Model.fit
sw = (np.arange(251) >= 36).astype('float64')
sw = np.reshape(sw, (1, sw.shape[0]))
sw = sw[:,:-36-84]

regressor = Sequential()
# an LSTM model of 3 layers
for k in range(3):
  if k == 0:
    regressor.add(LSTM(units = 200, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (None, 1)))
  else:
    regressor.add(LSTM(units = 200, return_sequences = True))
  regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units = 1)))

opt1 = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005,global_clipnorm=0.3)
regressor.compile(optimizer = opt1, loss = 'mean_squared_error')

callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=200, restore_best_weights=True)
history = regressor.fit(x, y, epochs = 10000, batch_size = x.shape[0], sample_weight=sw,
              validation_data=(x_val, y_val), callbacks=[callback])
```

I have the following question

1. Is it correct to set the sample_weight, so that it is like that the model will not output in the first 36 timesteps? Is there any other method?
2. Is it correct that I set input_shape = (None, 1) for the first LSTM layer? Because the training data and validation data have different timesteps.
3. Is my output layer correct? Each timestep has one output.
4. Will calculation of val_loss includes dropout layers?
5. After the computation is completed, I calculate the RMS of the validation data and compare it with the minimum val_loss. The values ​​​​are 0.00047 and 0.0010, respectively, so there is something wrong in my code.

Thank you very much.

The training data and validation data are not considered as a single sequence.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.